# AWS Route 53 not redirecting from www.example.com to example.com

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, amazon-route53

I have a working website at example.com that is stored in my S3. I bought my domain from google so it was a bit of trouble, but I transferred all my MX,CNAME, and other records. Now I have one hosted zone called `example.com`, inside it are all of these said records, plus amazon's default `SOA` and `NS` records. I tried making an `A` record to my `www.example.com` and it showed an error since a CNAME value had already taken up that slot. the CNAME's record looked like this:

```
www 3600    IN  CNAME   ghs.google.com
```

Unfortunately this did not work in terms of directing the `www` version to the no-prefix version of my website as it gave a DNS error. So I deleted this record and created an Alias with the name `www.example.com` and then connected it to my S3. (I know my S3 works because I checked the links that S3 provides).

It has been 12 hours and I still see no change in the behavior of looking up `www.example.com`. I should also note that I was fiddling around and created a new hosted zone for my `www.example.com` and followed the configuration and even added the 4 pieces of NS to my original DNS provider. I soon deleted them when I figured out this wasn't the correct method.

Please let me know of any suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: DNS does not do redirection. This is handle by the service responding to the request.

Comment: *I still see no change in the behavior of looking up www.example.com.*  You haven't mentioned what behavior you see.  `$ dig www.example.com` and edit your answer to include the lines in the "answer" section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it took 24 hours, not 12. So I guess the answer here is that patience is key! Thanks for attempting to help if you did!